# Can widow mines be denied with force fields?

Tags: starcraft-2

All is in the title. Is it possible to deny a mine shot with a force-field?

I have been in this situation, a team-mate has scanned a zone and reveal some widow mines on the my way to enemy base. I was wondering if I could run and place FF on the mine to avoid mines during my go trough. Because I don't wanted to loose my army, I haven't tried.

Comment: look up the "hots unittester" map where you can try this yourself

Comment: +1 for the unique idea! That said if you can't find anything better you can always try to sacrifice a zealot up the ramp to absorb the shot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**, widow mines' attacks are a spell, and as such they can cast it through the force field.

Units can't un-burrow when under force field, but widow mines attack from underground, and Immortals shield won't absorb widow damage since it is spell damage.

You should deny them with illusions or long range attacks.

Comment: Haven't played SC2 in a while,hope nothing changed

Comment: it changed, widow mines fire splash rockets on a cooldown

Comment: Does it change the answer ?

Comment: no it doesn't change the answer.

Comment: Didn't know about the new ranged attack,but it still doesn't change the answer.Those rockets are also a spell,only thing is that you can't use air units to clear them easily now.